# running a command at startup

Tags: command-line, docky

I know there are lots of questions about it on the internet but none of the solutions I've read seemed to work for me.

- I tried creating a script and putting my code in it - didn't work
- I tried writing the command directly in Startup Applications - didn't work.

the command I want to run is:
`LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=tr_TR.UTF-8 docky &`

I can run other commands with the methods mentioned above but for some reason they don't work for this particular command. So after a long research I ended up here...

Any suggestions?

And can someone please explain what's so special about this command? It's driving me crazy...

Comment: what was the exact command you want to execute at startup?

Comment: By startup you mean when machine power on or when you log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off this has to be startup application material. Second it's not sure `docky` is enough to run the application. In addition you lack `env` in the beginning.

So I guess you should try this as a command to a new entry of startup applications:

```
env LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=tr_TR.UTF-8 /path/to/docky
```

Comment: `docky` is what Docky itself uses so it is enough. And thanks it worked!